# Ruby on Rails: ActionController::RoutingError on VPS works fine in local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I run my rails server on port 80 on a VPS, usually the server is up for about 24 hours before I get an error:

I have done a fair few google searches and cannot seem to find the answer.

This isn't a problem when running on local, I had an error similar to this to do with the chkservd module, so maybe it is a similar issue this time?

```
   Started GET "/whm-server-status" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-13 16:10:01 -0600

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/whm-server-status"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (5.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (56.0ms)
```

Comment: A loopback entry might be missing in your hosts file. Try hitting the server using the IP

Comment: Thanks for the reply Musannif, I already am accessing the rails server using ip